# A pull contact force?

Tags: forces, surface-tension

I was wondering why when you spill liquids (mostly talking about water here) not all of it falls off but some of it remains on the cup or whatever that it was attached to.
I also noticed this while showering, when there's water on the ceiling some of it gathers to create a massive enough drop to fall off due to gravity (correct me if I'm wrong here).
So is it a force or is there a particular characteristic of the liquid/cup/ceiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), and more generally, [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(chemistry)).

The effect you're seeing is mostly due to the properties of the water, but the surface will have an effect in some cases. A sponge-like material will have more surface and thus hold more water (even upside down, like a sponge).

When two small drops touch, the cohesion between them will pull them towards each other. This is what causes the "building up" that forms a larger drop. Eventually, the weight of the drop is high enough to overcome the cohesion and down it comes. The formation of a drop is [surprisingly complex](http://Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh%20instability), no less than Rayleigh himself had to get involved.

Comment: I think that the adhesive force between the water and the surface (cup/ceiling) also plays a part?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot that.